# Clear ExtraSelections Qt on slot disconnect

Tags: c++, qt

I am implementing a focus mode in QT QTextEdit in which I am highlighting single line where cursor is present. So far I can enable focus mode but when I disable focus mode, i want the state restored back to what it was.

The function that calls connect and disconnect is:

```
void MainWindow::onFocus_Mode_triggered()
{
    QTextEdit *texed = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget());
    if(ui->actionFocus_Mode->isChecked()){
        connect(texed, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(highlightCurrentLine()));
    } 
    else {
        disconnect(texed, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(highlightCurrentLine())); //First disconnect and then call method to clear ExtraSelections
        BacktoNormal(); //Help needed in implementing this
    }
}
```

Now when the menu item actionFocus_Mode is checked, the line where the cursor is currently present is highlighted in yellow by the function given below.

```
void MainWindow::highlightCurrentLine() {

    QTextEdit *texed = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget());
    QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections;
    QTextEdit::ExtraSelection selection;
    QColor lineColor = QColor(Qt::yellow).lighter(160);

    selection.format.setBackground(lineColor);
    selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat::FullWidthSelection, true);
    selection.cursor = texed->textCursor();
    selection.cursor.clearSelection();
    extraSelections.append(selection);

    texed->setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
}
```

So I am able to highlight it in yellow but if(!ui->actionFocus_Mode->isChecked()), i.e, if menu item (focus mode) is unchecked then I wish to revert back to normal mode. How would I implement BacktoNormal() function.

What I think right now is that I should set lineColor to transparent or something to get it back to normal (if it is possible at all).
I am unable to find anything related to this. Any help would be useful as I am completely stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BackNormal` try to set just nothing as extra selections.

```
    QTextEdit *texed = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->textEdit);
    QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections;
    QTextEdit::ExtraSelection selection;
    QColor lineColor = QColor(Qt::yellow).lighter(160);

    selection.format.setBackground(lineColor);
    selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat::FullWidthSelection, true);
    selection.cursor = texed->textCursor();
    selection.cursor.clearSelection();
    extraSelections.append(selection);
    extraSelections.clear();//nothing

    texed->setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
```

When did I try this on my computer(with another code), this selections was successfully removed.

Smaller version:

```
    QTextEdit *texed = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(ui->textEdit);
    QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections;//empty list
    texed->setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Damn! It was so simple and I was thinking in a completely different direction.

Comment: @Bhavyanshu You are welcome. :) This place was created for this purpose, sometimes fresh look of another people can save much time.